# What do <useless> tags do in html?

Tags: html, tags

If I use an undefined `<useless>` tag like this

```
<useless>
Something here
</useless>
```

It still shows up normally as
**Something here**
in the browser. What do those actually do?
Will `id` and `class` work for those tags?

Comment: You'll find dozens of resources for you to read if you google `custom html tags`

Answer (score 0):

In html you can use any custom tags, the only difference between them and the default tags like h1 is that they don't have default styles. Everything works that works on a normal tag and you can reference them in css and js in the same way.

Some frameworks even make custom tags that they reference in their own code hence giving them custom properties.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML specification does not allow you to insert arbitrary elements into a page.

For purposes of forwards compatibility and not breaking *completely* when authors make errors, browsers will shove any unknown element onto the DOM.

It will not have any rules in the browser stylesheet, so will get the initial values for all properties.

It will not have any semantics associated with it so may cause issues for screen readers, other assistive technology and any analysis tools (like search engines) which make use of semantic data.

Don't write invalid HTML. Do use [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

---

Related are [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), which *are* standard, but which have the naming convention  `two-words` and specific rules for registering them using JavaScript.